# Formula to check is cells are blank. If the cell is not blank then assign a value

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula

I have a data set on Google Sheets where for example,

| Name | Stage 1 Date | Stage 2 Date | Stage 3 Date | Stage 4 Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | 3/1/2023 | 3/5/2023 | 3/31/2023 | 4/15/2023 |
| Joe | 2/1/2023 |  |  |  |
| Zoe | 3/21/2023 |  | 4/1/2023 | 4/15/2023 |
| Sam | 3/15/2023 |  | 4/1/2023 |  |

I am looking for a formula to return a value (Ex. 4) for the last date a person was in.

Ex Scenario 1 - The formula should return "4" for Bob.

Ex Scenario 2 - The formula should return "1" for Joe.

Ex Scenario 3 - The formula should return "4" for Zoe.

Ex Scenario 4 - The formula should return "3" for Sam.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have your table in A1:E5, try this out in row 2 of an empty column.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(BYROW(B2:E,LAMBDA(row,MATCH(,0/(row<>""))))))
```

Comment: Thanks this works!